# Alternating Sum of Binomial Coefficients Squared

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I was asked to prove that $\sum_{k = 0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}^2 = (-1)^m \binom{2m}{m}$, when $n = 2m$, and $0$ when n is odd.  I have seen other posts on this but I wasn't able to grasp this concept.  I'm looking for a direct proof of the identity.  I have tried using $(1 + X)^n (1 - X)^2 = (1 - X^2)^n$, and also brute force writing out the sum to try to cancel terms, but neither has quite got me to the final identity yet any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think the equation $(1+x)^n(1-x)^2=(1-x^2)^n$ always true? Try $x=2,$ for example.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096873/sum-k-0n-1k-binomnk2-and-sum-k-0n-k-binomnk2 and various other threads.

Comment: Combinatorial proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180150/alternating-sum-of-squares-of-binomial-coefficients/180440#180440

Comment: Allawonder I had a typo in my question as well

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}^2 &=& [x^k]: \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}  (1+x)^n \\
&=& [x^n]: \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} x^{n-k} (1+x)^n \\
&=& [x^n]: (x-1)^n (1+x)^n =[x^n]: (x^2-1)^n.
\end{eqnarray*}
It is clear that this zero if $n$ is odd. And if $n=2m$ then let $y=x^2$ and we want
\begin{eqnarray*}
[y^m]: (y-1)^{2m}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Edit : Explanation of notation ...

$[x^k]:f(x)$ means the coefficient of $x^n$ in the function $f(x)$. So for instance
\begin{eqnarray*}
\binom{n}{k}=[x^k]: (1+x)^n.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: This didn’t really clear it up for me as I don’t u defat and some of your notations

Comment: Understand* sorry made and a typo