# special sum of ratio of Gamma functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, special-functions, harmonic-analysis

Working on a harmonic analysis problem from the book, I came up with a difficulty of calculating the following sum. I figured how to solve original question, but it is a still interesting how to calculate this sum:

$$
\sum_{    \textit{ over odd values of  } i=0}^{\min {n, k }}\frac{\Gamma(1 + m) \Gamma(1 - m + 2 n)}{(\Gamma(1 + i) Γ((1 - i) + m) \Gamma((1 - i) + n) \Gamma((1 + i) - m + n))},
$$
where $n \in N$, $k\geq 0$ - even.

Comment: This is the same as
$$
\sum_{\text{odd }i=0}^{\min(m,n)}\binom{m}i\binom{2n-m}{n-i}
$$which is also
$$
=\frac12\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\min(m,n)}\binom{m}i\binom{2n-m}{n-i}+\sum_{i=0}^{\min(m,n)}(-1)^{i+1}\binom{m}i\binom{2n-m}{n-i}\right)
$$
The first summation is easy (Vandemonde's). The second at least has a nice answer when $m=n$, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180150/alternating-sum-of-squares-of-binomial-coefficients?noredirect=1&lq=1). When $m\neq n$, you can use a similar strategy, but it only lets you rewrite the summation as a different summation.

Comment: Thank you, Mike Earnest. I have gotten the Vandermonde's formula. My most confusion is the actual part when $m \neq n$. I am not sure on how to even represent it through other summations which would be helpful, i.e. which would be possible at least to estimate.

Comment: Since that *second sum* is $-[x^n](1-x)^m(1+x)^{2n-m}$ using the coefficient-of notation, the *other summations* are obtained by rewriting it *differently* as a product of two *known* series, say $(1-x^2)^m(1+x)^{2(n-m)}$. Whether this is useful depends on what you need exactly (what are *your* values of $m$ and $n$, what kind of *estimate* do you need, etc.)