# Binomial Theorem Derivative Identity

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-theorem

We want to prove that
$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k{n \choose k}^2=\ \Bigg\{
                \begin{array}
                 \ \hspace{2mm}0 \hspace{20mm}\text{ if n is odd} \\
                  \ (-1)^{\frac{n}{2}} {n \choose \frac{n}{2}}\hspace{6mm}\text{ if n is even}
                \end{array}$$
The odd proof is pretty easy by creating a bijection between odd and even subsets, but I cannot figure out the even proof. Any help would be significant!

Comment: Not my choice of dupe target, but yes, this is well-known. This is the perfect case for [approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5En%20(-1)%5Ek%7Bn%20%5Cchoose%20k%7D%5E2%24&p=1).

Comment: The second answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180150/alternating-sum-of-squares-of-binomial-coefficients) (by Mike Spivey) gives a very nice combinatorial argument that covers both the odd and the even case.